# Why is the distance travelled different in both the methods?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A point moves in X−Y plane according to X=a sin(wt) and Y=a (1−cos(wt)). If I calculate the distance travelled in time t, then distance travelled in x direction in time t is a sin(wt) and distance travelled in time t in y direction is a (1- cos(wt)). So total distance covered in time t is √( x²+y²), that is
 √(( a² sin²(wt)) + (a²(1-cos(wt))²))
= √(2a²(1-cos(wt)))
But if the calculate the velocity in x direction and y direction, then it turns out to be 'aw cos(wt)' and 'aw sin(wt)'. So resultant velocity is √(a²w² cos²(wt) + a²w² sin²(wt))
=aw. So distance travelled in time t is awt.
Why are both of the results different?
Is the first result displacement, not distance?
If so, then why?

Answer (score 0):

In the first method you are finding the magnitude of the displacement vector $\vec OA$ and in your second method $a\omega$ is the speed and you have found the distance travelled along arc $OA$.

[image]

Try using time $t = \dfrac {2\pi}{\omega}$ and see what you get for the magnitude of the displacement and the distance.